# ERROR: ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, rds, amazon-aurora

I was helping a friend migrate his WordPress to AWS. The whole WordPress was exported by him using WPClone and I'm going to import it to RDS (Aurora). I'm not a pro DB guy and I only knew basic MySQL commands. I was trying to restore a database but during the restoration I encountered `ERROR: ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint`.

I executed `show engine innodb status` and checked the `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` and this is what I got but I have no idea how to resolve this.

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2017-03-10 11:22:06 2b87437cb700 Error in foreign key constraint of table clientdb/wp_supsystic_ss_project_networks:
 FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `wp_supsystic_ss_projects` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8:
Cannot resolve table name close to:
 (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Here's the `create table` for `wp_supsystic_ss_networks`, `wp_supsystic_ss_project_networks` and `wp_supsystic_ss_projects`:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_supsystic_ss_networks` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `class` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `brand_primary` varchar(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '#000000',
  `brand_secondary` varchar(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '#ffffff',
  `total_shares` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `wp_supsystic_ss_project_networks` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `project_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `network_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tooltip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `text_format` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `use_short_url` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `icon_image` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK__wp_supsystic_ss_projects` (`project_id`),
  KEY `FK__wp_supsystic_ss_networks` (`network_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK__wp_supsystic_ss_networks` FOREIGN KEY (`network_id`) REFERENCES `wp_supsystic_ss_networks` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK__wp_supsystic_ss_projects` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `wp_supsystic_ss_projects` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `wp_supsystic_ss_projects` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `settings` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: can you post `create table` script for both the tables in the context.

Comment: Hello @RavinderReddy! I have updated my question. Thank you!

Comment: If `project_networks` is a many:many mapping table, see the advice [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) - among other tips, get rid if `id` and have `PRIMARY KEY(project_id, network_id)` and `INDEX(network_id, project_id)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Create tables in this order: **child tables**, **parent table** (with foreign keys). Replace CREATE TABLE statements:

   - `wp_supsystic_ss_projects`
   - `wp_supsystic_ss_networks`
   - `wp_supsystic_ss_project_networks`.
2. Child table `wp_supsystic_ss_networks` does not exist in the script.